# How to update a SQL database table based on condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that inserts values from a table into another table, see below:

```
USE [DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
                CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAverageRunTimings]

                    (
                        @LatesVersionTested varchar(50) =  NULL
                    )
                AS
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark( LatestVersionTested, TestCode, TestSequence, AverageRuntime)
                    SELECT  LatestVersionTested, TestCode, TestSequence, AverageRuntime
                    FROM #temptable2
                    WHERE  LatestVersionTested  NOT IN (SELECT LatestVersionTested FROM TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark)

     END
```

Temptable2 and TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark have information like this:

```
LatestVersionTested TestSequence    AverageRuntime
3.21 - 48 Update 78    1                 5.34
3.21 - 48 Update 78    15                6.32
3.21 - 48 Update 78    16                5.93
3.21 - 48 Update 78    17                21.09
3.21 - 48 Update 78    18                0.64
3.21 - 48 Update 78    19                0.15
3.21 - 48 Update 78    20                0.12
3.21 - 48 Update 78    21                0.12
3.21 - 48 Update 78    22                0.91
3.21 - 48 Update 78    25                13.93
3.21 - 48 Update 95    1                 1.40
3.21 - 48 Update 95    15                0.74
3.21 - 48 Update 95    16                1.27
3.21 - 48 Update 95    17                5.27
3.21 - 48 Update 95    18                3.62
3.21 - 48 Update 95    19                2.53
3.21 - 48 Update 95    20                2.52
3.21 - 48 Update 95    21                2.33
3.21 - 48 Update 95    22                0.61
3.21 - 48 Update 95    25                2.05
3.21 - 48 Update 93    1                 1.58
3.21 - 48 Update 93    15                0.85
3.21 - 48 Update 93    16                1.45
3.21 - 48 Update 93    17                5.18
3.21 - 48 Update 93    18                3.48
3.21 - 48 Update 93    19                2.50
3.21 - 48 Update 93    20                2.48
3.21 - 48 Update 93    21                2.16
3.21 - 48 Update 93    22                0.70
3.21 - 48 Update 93    25                2.36
```

If values in the LatestVersionTested column in temptable2 are not found in LatestVersionTested column in TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark table then the  stored procedure inserts those values.

What I want to achieve is, If the LatestVersionTested in both tables are the same, the AverageRuntime values in temptable2 must replace the AverageRuntime in the TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark table values

How can I modify my stored procedure to achieve this?

Comment: Which is the primary key in TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark? I think it is not only 'LatestVersionTested' but also 'TestCode', however, in your WHERE clause you are only looking not to find 'LatestVersionTested', should you add all your PK fields in order to avoid duplicates?

Comment: @SergioPrats primary key is the TestSequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAverageRunTimings]

(
@LatesVersionTested varchar(50) =  NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT LatestVersionTested  FROM TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark WHERE LatestVersionTested= @LatesVersionTested)
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark SET AverageRuntime= a.AverageRuntime 
    FROM #temptable2 a
    WHERE LatestVersionTested =@LatesVersionTested

    END ELSE BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark( LatestVersionTested, TestCode, TestSequence, AverageRuntime)
    SELECT  LatestVersionTested, TestCode, TestSequence, AverageRuntime
    FROM #temptable2
    WHERE  LatestVersionTested = @LatesVersionTested

  END

END
```

Answer (score 0):

If your stored proc is inserting all the records you require, then there shouldn't be any that aren't in both.

You would have to look at more than just the latest version however, as it is not unique, but the combination of the latest version and the test sequence are.

You are not taking the test sequence into consideration on your INSERT, is it that a versions test sequence will only ever be inserted in one go?

If that is true, you could do something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAverageRunTimings]

    @LatesVersionTested varchar(50) =  NULL

    AS
    BEGIN

        /*Insert missing records*/
       INSERT INTO TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark
            ( 
                LatestVersionTested, 
                TestCode, 
                TestSequence, 
                AverageRuntime
            )
        SELECT  LatestVersionTested, 
                TestCode, 
                TestSequence, 
                AverageRuntime
        FROM    #temptable2
        WHERE   LatestVersionTested  NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT  LatestVersionTested 
            FROM    TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark
        )
        /*Update the records so the runtimes match as all records are now inserted*/
        UPDATE      PB
        SET         PB.AverageRuntime                   =   T2.AverageRunTime
        FROM        TestingToolTestPerfomanceBenchmark  AS  PB
        INNER JOIN  #TempTable2                         AS  T2  ON  PB.LatestVersionTested = T2.LatestVersionTested AND PB.TestSequence     = T2.TestSequence   
        WHERE       PB.AverageRuntime                   <>  T2.AverageRuntime;


     END
```